# How to get multiple integer values from EditText in Activity A to show min and max in TextView in Activity B?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is regarding to an app in android studio that i'm building.
I have 2 activities.

In activity A, I have 4 EditTexts that can only contain integer. 
Min button:there is a button, that should calculate the minimum of those 4 numbers entered by user.
Max button:there is a button, that should calculate the maximum of those 4 numbers entered by user.

In activity B, there are 6 `TextView`s (4 for numbers, 2 for Min and Max).
When the `Button` in `Activity` A is pressed. It should pass the numbers from the `EditText`s in `Activity` A to the `TextView`s in `Activity` B. In addition to that, it should show the average of the 4 numbers in Results `TextView`.

I figured out the way how to pass the numbers to the `TextView`s in the second `Activity`.
What I want is a code that calculates the min and max of the user inputs and shows the min and max result in the `TextView` in `Activity` B.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to get the numbers from all of your `Textview` and set them in Integer List, After that, you can check the numbers using `Collections`

And the following is the example code for that:

```
 List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(100,2,3,4,5,6,7,67,2,32);

 int min = Collections.min(list);
 int max = Collections.max(list);

 System.out.println(min);
 System.out.println(max);
```

Output:

```
2
100
```

Of course, you will have to set the output in `Textview` instead of `System.out.println`

Comment: well in my case i don't know the numbers.
when the app starts the editTexts are empty then user enter the numbers in 4 editTexts and then i should get the min and max of these 4 numbers that are entered by user.
i don't know what code to use to get the min and max value of 4 numbers.

Comment: you dont need to know the numbers that was just example, what you need to do is: when the user click on Min Button check every edittext you have if its not empty it will take the number in it and put it in the array and than move to next edittext do the same thing and move to next untill you finish with checking and than you run my code and if all of the values are empty and theres nothing in the array list than theres no point to run the code, instead you can show Toast and tell the user he need to give input first